# Can use the optgroup option on div?

Tags: optgroup

have this optgroup select it is possible to use a javascript for this and if yes can show me an example how can do that i have look around but i do not find something?

```
Choose a city:
<select name="city">
  <optgroup label="color_1">
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Colors 2"> 
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option> 
    <option value="Grey">Grey</option> 
    <option value="White">White</option> 
  </optgroup> 
</select>

But i want use group for div class for example

<div class="categories">


<span class="optgroup" id="color_1">
   <div class="category">Colors 1</div>
  <label class="color_1">Blue</label>
  <label class="color_1">Red</label>
  <label class="color_1">Green</label>
</span>

<span class="optgroup" id="color_2">
   <div class="category">Colors 2</label >
      <label class="color_2">Yellow</label>
  <label class="color_2">Grey</label>
  <label class="color_2">White</label>
</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Just style the optgroup class to resemble the select optgroup.

Comment: Can do this with some javascript?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just the looks or the functionality as well?

Comment: A functionality! I want make the name of category as button and the subcategory in the dropdown of the category button

Comment: Oh, that's a bit more complicated. I don't think anyone here would give you the full code. You must show what you tried so far, etc... we only address specific problems here.